# How can I read stdio on ESP8266 NodeMCU

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to read user input from the Lua console, but do not seem to be able to read from stdio

```
print("Enter your name:")
if file.open("stdio") then
  line = file.read("*a")
  file.close()
  print("Hello "..line)
end
```

My firmware has modules `file,gpio,net,node,ow,tmr,uart,wifi,tls`

if I try `io.read("*a")` I get error  `Lua error:  stdin:1: attempt to index global 'io' (a nil value)`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no io library in the NodeMCU firmware. Hence you cannot call `io.read`

If you want to read serial input you can use the uart library.
https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/uart/

> ```
> -- when 4 chars is received.
> uart.on("data", 4,
>   function(data)
>     print("receive from uart:", data)
>     if data=="quit" then
>       uart.on("data") -- unregister callback function
>     end
> end, 0)
> -- when '\r' is received.
> uart.on("data", "\r",
>   function(data)
>     print("receive from uart:", data)
>     if data=="quit\r" then
>       uart.on("data") -- unregister callback function
>     end
> end, 0)
> ```